Will NVARCHAR(max) columns benefit from row compression?
I have a table that I believe owes most of its size to a huge NVARCHAR(max) column. I do not know how to test where most of its size comes from. Regardless, would such a table benefit from row compression? Or is NVARCHAR(max) already variable-length in such a way that row compression is guaranteed to do nothing?

No.  With row compression nvarchar(n) will benefit from Unicode Compression.  But not nvarchar(max).
Because the data is uncompressed, you can measure the storage size with datalength:
select avg(datalength(SomeCol)) AvgLenBytes, count(SomeCol) NumValues, sum(datalength(SomeCol)) TotalBytes
from SomeTable

If the large column is infrequently accessed, you can sometimes improve performance by forcing all the values out of the main row, with sp_tableoption, setting large value types out of row.
If you access the nvarchar(max) column every time you access the row, then it won't help.  But if you select the other columns more frequently, especially if you are scanning the whole table, then pushing the nvarchar(max) off row can help.
